# Alter function name using #define

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Could I implement this in **C**?

```
#define X abc
```

then `X_menu();` will be preprocessed as `abc_menu();`

In another build 
if I `define X def`
then `X_menu();` will be `def_menu();`

I'm sure there should be a method, but I could not figure out.

Comment: If users could do this then internal details of standard libraries would need to be named `__l__i__k__e__t__h__i__s` and also I would want to strangle people. Actually even that wouldn't work ... standard libraries would be impossible to implement safely.

Comment: The usual convention is not to play such tricks with the preprocessor. Even the (working) answer by Ryan Haining should not be used: The indirection adds a big speedbump for the reader, and the savings in typing is minimal. If you must some kind of automatic tool to shortcut your typing, use editior abbreviations. Learning to touch-type helps as well.

Comment: really don't understand this.

Comment: @user1932637 what I gave you works but is a bad idea to actually use

Comment: why do you think it's bad idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253934/c-pre-processor-defining-for-generated-function-names

this is better solution.


thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you wouldn't want this behavior as it would be very unsafe and difficult to deal with replacing every `X` in every name.  However, you could use a macro function to do something similar

```
#define X(F) abc##F
X(_menu();)
```

`##` is macro concatenation, so `X(_menu();)` will expand to `abc_menu();`

As [Roger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8446/roger-lipscombe) points out, the macro will also work with the syntax

```
X(_menu)();
```

which you may find easier to read

Comment: `X(_menu)();` is easier on the eye, imo.

Comment: Ha, it's tricky. cool! the only thing I don't like is you have to define X(F) rather than X. is there another to solve it?

Comment: @user1932637 afaict, nothing nicer than this while still only using the preprocessor, if you start doing your own code generation then the possibilities are endless