# generate a name for macro with another macro (c preprocessor)

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I can generate name for a function using an macro which is taken from [C pre-processor defining for generated function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253934/c-pre-processor-defining-for-generated-function-names) .

```
#define POSTFIX _ABC //_ABC should be mentioned only there
#define PROTOTYPENAME(symbol) symbol ## POSTFIX
#define PROTOTYPENAMED(sym) PROTOTYPENAME(sym)

int PROTOTYPENAMED(Function)(int a, int b, int c);
```

Above would result as

```
int Function_ABC(int a, int b, int c);
```

If I want to generate equivalent for `#define ANOTHERFUNCTION_ABC WhatsThat()` I might want to write

```
#define PROTOTYPENAMED(ANOTHERFUNCTION) WhatsThat()
```

but this will redefine a `PROTOTYPENAMED` macro. Is there a way to do it correctly without writing `_ABC` everywhere?

PS. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and code should work in C and C++.

Edit:
alk: this question contains more useful answer how to do this using another tools. You should not mark this question as dublicate.

Edit 2:
I was thinking about alternatives that do not need an external tools. Maybe it is not needed to declare it as macro? If we assume `WhatsThat()` is returning `int`, it is not forbidden to write `int PROTOTYPENAMED(ANOTHERFUNCTION) = WhatsThat();`.

Comment: Explain this in more defails - I have completely no idea what you're trying to achieve. The first thought is that you are probably trying to "overload" a macro, that is, you want that it do different things depending on what name you pass as 'name' to 'PROTOTYPENAMED' macro. How would you like to use the"second version"of that macro and what result would you like to achieve?

Comment: @Ethouris read an question again, macro overloading is unexpected behaviour. _I might want to write_ `#define PROTOTYPENAMED(ANOTHERFUNCTION) WhatsThat()` _to generate_ `#define ANOTHERFUNCTION_ABC WhatsThat()`

Comment: So, yes, as Basile said, it's not possible to achieve in C/C++ preprocessor. This better be some completely generator-based thing. I personally use Tcl for that, not only because I like it, but that it can simply contain the whole text in {...} without any special "escapes". Then you can either contain $variables inside or have some unique-impossible-in-normal-program statmenents that will be next replaced by simple search-replace ("string map" command in Tcl) - such as @KEY@ used in *.in files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not doable with the standard C/C++ preprocessor. However, you might feed your compiler using some C++ or C source generator, like e.g. the [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) or the [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) preprocessors, or some script -e.g. in Python, `awk`, `guile`, ...- (or program) of yours.

<sup>For example, [`yacc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) or `bison` and [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) generate C++ code. And [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is compiled into C++ code.</sup>

Of course, you need to configure your builder accordingly, e.g. add some more [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) rules.