# Use expanded result of macro as parameter to other macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

There is a macro that I want to use that takes arguments in this format:

```cpp
COMB(unique identifier, argument 1, argument 2, argument 3)
```

I want to create a wrapper for it that automatically generates the unique identifier. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624752) that has code to generate a random ID, which I am using in my code:

```cpp
#define PP_CAT(a, b) PP_CAT_I(a, b)
#define PP_CAT_I(a, b) PP_CAT_II(~, a ## b)
#define PP_CAT_II(p, res) res

#define UNIQUE_NAME(base) PP_CAT(base, __COUNTER__)

#define COMB_U(key, ...) COMB(UNIQUE_NAME(comb_r_), key, __VA_ARGS__)

// Using the macro
// The parameters are enums
COMB_U(KB_1, KB_2, KC_Y)
```

When I compile this I get a bunch of errors from inside of the COMB macro code like this:

> ‘cmb_UNIQUE_NAME’ declared as function returning an array
>
> function ‘cmb_UNIQUE_NAME’ is initialized like a variable

As well as inside of the file with my code:

> ‘comb_r_’ undeclared here (not in a function)
>
> #define COMB_U(key, ...) COMB(UNIQUE_NAME(comb_r_), key, **VA_ARGS**)

And a bunch of messages that don't seem to be associated with an error, like this one:

> note: in expansion of macro ‘COMB_U’
>
> COMB_U(KB_1, KB_2, KC_Y)

How can I fix this?

For reference, the source for the COMB macro is here: https://github.com/germ/qmk_firmware/blob/master/keyboards/gboards/g/keymap_combo.h

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28327732/10142251) should answer your question.

Comment: That question is about generating a name for a macro, but I'm trying to generate a parameter that will be passed to a macro.