# Completing a macro's name with another macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I use a library that defines macros. I can make a modification to this library and recompile it but on the condition of not breaking compatibility i.e without impacting anything.

I would like to be able to prefix the name of its macros when compiling the library. So currently, I have:

```
// In the library :
#define function(i) { cout << i; }

 // In my application:
function(i);
```

I would like to recompile the library by adding a personal define: -DMYPREFIX_
and use it in this way in my application:

MYPREFIX_function(i);

...and thus make the original macro disappear to avoid name conflicts with others library for example.

I'm struggling a bit..

Comment: No, I'm 99% sure preprocessor cannot generate a name of a macro from expansion of another macro. The result of preprocessor expansion is never interpreted as a preprocessor instruction. You'd likely need a separate code generation step - a script that massages the source code of the library to insert your prefixes, after which you would compile the modified source.

Comment: Personally, this is one of the many reasons why macros should be avoided.

Comment: You're right, I have to face the facts, this doesn't seem possible.. Maybe m4 is adapted to this type of need. In my case a sed script does the trick.
Possibly a duplicate of the following question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327691/generate-a-name-for-macro-with-another-macro-c-preprocessor